# What is the difference between "you're so not cool" & "you're not so cool"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-order, word-difference

I think "**so**" in "**you're so not cool**" emphasizes the whole sentence.

Whereas, "**so**" in "**you're not so cool**" emphasizes "**cool**", meaning "**very cool**".

I am not sure whether I'm right.

So,  What is the difference between "**you're so not cool**" & "**you're not so cool**"?

Comment: @JavaLatte, it is not a duplicate. It means something else

Comment: It's about the relative positions of "not" and "so", and as you pointed out, the meaning of "so" in these sentences is "very".

Comment: @JavaLatte it's a good point and I've posted a question in meta about this [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3024/how-can-an-op-find-similar-questions-and-avoid-posting-a-duplicate-question)

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question as it is not a duplicate and is really related with English Language Learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: you're correct.

Long-form:
The use of "**so**" in

> You're so not cool.

is extremely idiomatic, and informal.  It's used to emphasize the degree to which "you" are "not cool".  The result is a superlative statement, in a way, declaring the level of "not-cool-ness" to be extreme, and beyond measure.  Verbally, the word "**so**" would be strongly stressed.

Compare:

> You're not cool.
>
> You're ***so*** not-cool *[that I'm at a loss for words to express myself further]*.

This construct would be well placed in the film "Mean Girls", delivered as an insult with a dismissive and exasperated affect.

Conversely, placing "**so**" after "**not**" is much more thoughtful, (though still critical.)  In this case the sentence suggests that the listener has an overly-inflated ego, or perhaps that the speaker formerly thought that the listener was once a "cooler" person than they are now perceived to be.  The "**not**" is used as a polarity switch, and "**so**" is used as a modifier of "**cool**".

Compare:

> You're so cool.
>
> You're not so cool *[as you think you are/as I thought you were]*.

This phrasing would likely show up in a light comedy scene, as a form of criticism, but lacking malice.  It could be said between friends, and be at least forgivable, or maybe delivered and taken entirely as a joke, or "ribbing".

One may notice here that, as is common in English, both examples are used as shorthand to express a longer idea, which I spelled out in [square brackets], making them both "jargon", and incomplete in themselves.

Citing my source:  I'm a native speaker of American English, raised in California, with some college, several years of customer service communication, and an author for a parent.  Practical linguistics is a hobby.

Comment: Very nice answer.